# Docker not exposing my application to run locally

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I've an express application which looks as follows:

```js
const express = require("express");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app = express();

app.all("*", (req, res) =>
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 200,
    message: "Hello world from Docker.",
  })
);

app.listen(PORT, "127.0.0.1", () =>
  console.log("The server is running on port: %s", PORT)
);
```

I want to build an image based on this simple express application so my `Dockerfile` looks as follows:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

`.dockerignore` looks as follows:

```
node_modules
```

This is how i built my image:

```bash
docker build -t my-app:1.0 .
```

Now if i start an image locally as follows:

```
docker run -p 3001:3001 my-app:1.0
```

And if i visit on my web-browser at `http://localhost:3001`, there's nothing showing in the browser.

OS: `Windows 10`

What am i missing here?

Comment: Remove the 127.0.0.1 in app.js because that makes the app listening to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose the app for external connections this way:

```js
app.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0", () =>
  console.log("The server is running on port: %s", PORT)
);
```